# Efficient way to query a cache using different parameters

Tags: java, caching, hashmap

This is a sample problem for a use case what i am trying to solve.
there is a table in Database which has the daily time consumed while travelling between two places, this table is moderately small i.e having 50k entries. so we want to cache around this table to reduce the DB load.  So the problem statement is return me the time taken to travel between to places X and Y on a particular date.

This same query can be executed n number of times so we need to take care of space while implementing the solution.

below is my implementation i have removed the code to fetch the data from DB to remove the clutter.  for simplification you can assume the table has 4 columns 
Travelled_date, from, to, Time_taken.

the cache has two methods exposed to the end user to get time,  there is a issue in my current implementation when user passes from/to/ and date to fetch the time.  here i am every time creating the object of TravelledPlaces which i made immutable but yet subsequent calls to the cache with same params will create multiple TravelledPlaces object which will eat up main memory.  any recommendations to avoid multiple creations of this object for same invocation ?

following is the code

```
public class TimeConsumedCache {

private Map<Date, Map<TravelledPlaces, Double>> timeCache = new HashMap<Date, Map<TravelledPlaces, Double>>();

public double getTimeTravelled(Date date, TravelledPlaces tp) {
    return timeCache.get(date).get(tp);
}

public double getTimeTravelled(Date date, String from, String to) {
    return timeCache.get(date).get(new TravelledPlaces(from, to));
}

private static final class TravelledPlaces {
    private String fromLocation;
    private String toLocation;

    public TravelledPlaces(String fromLocation, String toLocation) {
        this.fromLocation = fromLocation;
        this.toLocation = toLocation;
    }

    //hashcode and equals removed for brevity

}

  }
```

how about if i directly use

```
  timeCache.get(date).get(from + to)); and change cache definition to 
  Map<Date, Map<String, Double>>  but this loses the object oriented approach of  dealing with the problem
```

Comment: You put 50k entries in timeCache ? If yes, first, create your HashMap with a capacity because if you call put 50k times, it will be slow to load: the capacity will be 16, 32, 64, 128, ...

Comment: one question : Are you sure `timeCache.get(date)` is never null?

Comment: Thanks @AthaNor thanks for the suggestions,  
2UmNyob this is just a dummy implementation hence didnt put the null checks Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> every time creating the object of TravelledPlaces which i made
>   immutable but yet subsequent calls to the cache with same params will
>   create multiple TravelledPlaces object which will eat up main memory

This is an incorrect assumption.

```
return timeCache.get(date).get(new TravelledPlaces(from, to));
```

will not eat up memory. The object used for the query is going to be garbage collected. And I can assume with a decent optimization, memory overhead is going to be near the size of one object.

One issue may come from the size of `timeCache`. Successively adding elements from zero to 50k is going to requires the increase of the container capacity.

If you build the cache in a lazy manner, by adding elements only when they are absent this cost is going to be amortized. If for any reason you **have to** build the entire cache beforehand, then I suggest using only one map and

```
class DatedTravelledPlaces
{
   private Date date;
   private TravelledPlaces places;

    DatedTravelledPlaces(Date date, String from, String to)
    {
      //construction
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      //same as what you did with TravelledPlaces 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      //same as what you did with TravelledPlaces 
    }
}

public class TimeConsumedCache {
    private Map<DatedTravelledPlaces, double> timeCache;


     TimeConsumedCache()
     {
       int dbsize = computeDBSize();
       timeCache = new HashMap<DatedTravelledPlaces, double>(dbsize );
     }

}
```

Comment: timeCache.get(date).get(new TravelledPlaces(from, to));
will not eat up memory isn't it also an assumption ?  please could you please tell me the rationale behind it as the objects would be residing in the main memory until GC'd should we rely on this ..  just a thought had i used "from" + "to" string as a key we would avoid creating objects  as strings will be returned from the pool but i think that isn't a good approach

Comment: @Dhirendra It is not an assumption. I didnt say it will not require memory. But "eating up"? no. You will not see memory increase by an iota. `new TravelledPlaces(from, to)` is candidate for garbage collection as soon as `get(new TravelledPlaces(from, to))` returns. If you dont believe me attach a profiler and see for yourself.